# Removing QComboBox "Drop-Down" Animation

Tags: c++, qt, windows-7

I am using Qt 4.8 and would like to get rid of the "Drop-Down" animation when clicking on a QComboBox. I also want to move it a bit. So far I've been looking at re-implementing showPopup and hidePopup but can't figure out how to make it work.

Additionally, every time I try to move or style using CSS there is a white background that is always there. (See picture). Any help would be appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Suggestion: one question at a time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [QApplication::setEffectEnabled](http://doc.qt.digia.com/qt/qapplication.html#setEffectEnabled):

```
QApplication::setEffectEnabled(Qt::UI_AnimateCombo, false);
```