# QComboBox::showPopup() with no animation

Tags: c++, qt, qcombobox, qtgui

Is there a simple way to use `QComboBox::showPopup()` without the animation making it instant?

Comment: duplicate ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14150748/removing-qcombobox-drop-down-animation

Comment: Yes, that's what I needed QApplication::setEffectEnabled(Qt::UI_AnimateCombo, false);. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See code:

```
QApplication::setEffectEnabled(Qt::UI_AnimateCombo, false);
```